# Windows Server 2012 Updates Fail with Error 024402F or 8024402C

Tags: windows-server-2012

I am running Windows Server 2012 on a virtual machine. I used to get Windows update but it stopped getting them automatically.  Each I try to check for updates, I get the error 8024402F or 8024402C.  Does anybody know why and what I need to do to fix it?

Also on the same Windows Server 2012 virtual machine, I cannot run any command on Powershell.  Each time I type a command on Powershell, I get only red errors. If I run for example the command, "update-help," I get a bunch of red texts starting with the phrase "update-help failed....."  Any reason why I can run commands on Powershell?

Thanks,

Comment: What are your firewall settings like? Also, is this a hosted server on say an AWS instance?

Comment: Did you run the powershell update-help command as admin?

Comment: Are you using WSUS to manage updates?

Comment: Elliot, yes, I did run the Powershell command as an admin.

Comment: For the 2nd question, I am using WSUS to manage updates.  The Windows Server 2012 is on a virtual machine but I can easily get updates on the host machine without any problem.

Comment: I resolved the problem with not being able to get updates on Windows Server 2012.  The problem was the DNS IP address was on manual with the loopback address 127.0.0.1.  Now, I just need to know why I cannot run commands on the Powershell.